# Table exceeding parent

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with a table exceeding the width of it's container. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on here. Oh, it only occurs in firefox as well. Here's the link:
http://in3applications.com/rothseed-qa/corn.php

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: It occurs in IE11, too...

Comment: If it doesn't fit, it doesn't fit :/ From my perspectice, there's no room left or to spare, the table **is** that big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set all `th img` width to `25px` which under the "Available Technologies" column. 
Firefox seems not support the `max-width` for `img` tag under `th`

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow
Set width to 98% OR
Ser  margin left and right and maybe top and bottom to 0px OR ir it still dos not work ser margins to 1px
If it is centeres ser algo margin 0 auto; 
If that does not work let me See your test site OR html code

Comment: Ah sorry I looked at it now from my cell and I See it so set margin left and right to 0px if not to -1 there must be some padding causing the trouble OR the float is not left OR 0 auto

Comment: Cell phone keyboards ... I will check from Pc and help you right away

Answer (score 0):

Add box-sizing:border-box to your table's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The table's width is the sum of all the width of the cells making up the rows.

In your example, the overall width of the table exceeds the width of the parent block, 
so you are seeing an overflow condition.

Your table is too wide for the width you have prescribed.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout

There is not much you can do about this except shrink the font of the content within the table, but then, it may make the table hard to read.

You could also try `table-layout: fixed` and set the width on some of the columns that need some space for the text, and the rest of the columns will shrink to fit.

You need to experiment a bit more.

Note: You have set the text in the vertical header labels as images with a fair amount of
space, you could shrink the margins around the text (in the images) to save some space.